# Hide category headline if static block is enabled (magento)

Tags: magento

How to remove/hide category headline if I choose that category shows static blocks + products, so in static block I attaching image with category name (for example, brands/manufacturer banner) so I don't need the same headline.

Any solutions?

Comment: For example - http://cl.ly/290H2O3n3S432d2Z300Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<?php if($imageUrl=!$this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):?>
```

this will be check if the current category has an image.